# Windows Server 2019 - VMs on Hyper-V cant get network

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, windows-server, esxi

I have some trouble with my windows server 2019 running Hyper-V, for the background my windows server run on an ESXI infra.

It is impossible for me to get any internet access nor domain access on my Hyper-V virtual machine, this is how my host configuration look like

[Host network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rEXK.png)

For me all look good, but when I turn on my virtual machine this is what I get

[VMs network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3WXc.png)

[VMs ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdSY7.png)

I can see the machine getting a IP from my DHCP server, but it is impossible for me to ping any of the gateway, DNS.

[My DHCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90IRd.png)

This is how my virtual switch look like

[vSwitch Hyper-V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bbkx.png)

And if needed my Ipconfig of my Windows server Hyper-V host

[Hyper-V host network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilbin.png)

I think that i have now tried everything I could, I don't see why my machine can get a DHCP IP, but can't communicate with any of my server.

I already have a topic posted on SpiceWorks (https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2326264-hyper-v-wont-provide-internet-access-on-my-virtual-machine?page=1#entry-9231547), the last answer suggested that the problem came from my vSwitch on Hyper-V, but even after recreating a new one I can't get anything.

If you have any idea that can help me to achieve my configuration even the slightest one I'll gladly take it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would like to ask, you are doing a Double Nested Virtualization, meaning:   [ESXi] is the BareMetal Hypervisor, then inside of this Host you have at least 2 VMs,  one name "SRVPARDC001" &  the Hyper-V VM named "TESTHYPERV" ,  and inside this last one you have another VM called "VDI-Master" , if this is correct, you are asking:
*Why is VDI-Master, not getting internet, when SRVPARDC001 has leased an IP address ( 192.168.1.118) ?

My question is, why does the ipconfig output for VDI-Master show IP 192.168.1.121 , which per your DHCP, should be leased to the Desktop

Would it be possible to use a different subnet for the Virtual Switch inside the Hyper-V , to eliminate routing/dhcp issues?

My impression is that there is an issue on how the virtual switch is configured on the TESTHYPERV vm, since that virtual switch should be allowing the traffic upstream to the ESXi host and then out via your gateway/router/firewall device.